# Same Recipe and Model with Different Outcomes

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes, r-parsnip

I have a dataset with multiple columns for the outcome variables that I would like to predict with the same preprocessing steps and models. Is there a way to run the same recipe and models (with tuning - I'm using `workflow_map()`) on multiple outcome variables (separate models for each outcome)?

Essentially, I want loop through the same preprocessing steps and models for each outcome. Basically I want to avoid having to do this:

```r
model_recipe1 <- recipe(outcome_1 ~ ., data) %>%
                 step_1

model_recipe2 <- recipe(outcome_2 ~ ., data) %>%
                 step_1

model_recipe3 <- recipe(outcome_3 ~ ., data) %>%
                 step_1
```

and would instead like to do something like this:

```r
model_recipe <- recipe(outcome[i] ~ ., data) %>%
                 step_1
```

Comment: I haven't used `workflow_map()` but I guess it could be doing something random involving a seed. You could try adding `set.seed(123)` before any part of your modelling that could involve a random starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if we 100% recommend the approach you are trying, but it will work in some circumstances:

```r
library(tidymodels)

folds <- bootstraps(mtcars, times = 5)
wf_set <- workflow_set(list(mpg ~ ., wt ~ ., disp ~ .), list(linear_reg()))
workflow_map(wf_set, "fit_resamples", resamples = folds)
#> # A workflow set/tibble: 3 × 4
#>   wflow_id             info             option    result   
#>   <chr>                <list>           <list>    <list>   
#> 1 formula_1_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
#> 2 formula_2_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
#> 3 formula_3_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To make many recipes in an iterative fashion, you'll need a bit of metaprogramming [such as with rlang](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#quoting). You can write a function to take (in this case) a string and create a recipe:

```r
library(rlang)

my_recipe <- function(outcome) {
  form <- new_formula(ensym(outcome), expr(.))
  recipe(form, data = mtcars) %>%
    step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())
}
```

And then you can use this function with `purrr::map()` across your outcomes:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(rlang)

folds <- bootstraps(mtcars, times = 5)

wf_set <- workflow_set(
  map(c("mpg", "wt", "disp"), my_recipe), 
  list(linear_reg())
  )

workflow_map(wf_set, "fit_resamples", resamples = folds)
#> # A workflow set/tibble: 3 × 4
#>   wflow_id            info             option    result   
#>   <chr>               <list>           <list>    <list>   
#> 1 recipe_1_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
#> 2 recipe_2_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
#> 3 recipe_3_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try running this once before the rest of your code

```
set.seed(123)
```

If that doesn't solve it, try running [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989898/5783745) once at the start of your script:

```
addTaskCallback(function(...) {set.seed(123);TRUE})
```

Both of these methods try to ensure any random processes provide the same outcomes each time you run your script, allowing reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Stevec. I'm not worried about getting the same results each time the model is run, I just want to switch out the dependent variables. Essentially, I want the model to loop through each of my individual outcomes so that instead of copy and pasting the code for each outcome, I can just write it once and have some way of automatically changing the outcome.

Comment: @nrjenkins gotcha. I'm not too familiar with workflows, so I'm not too sure. But hopefully someone with experience in them can provide some pointers.