# Is there a way to add a pre-hook in R?

Tags: r, callback, hook

The function `addTaskCallback()` allows you to add some custom code that will run *after* other code ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989898/5783745)).

Is there a way in R of achieving the opposite, that is, to add some code that will run *before* other code?

#### What I know so far

I know I could edit the actual script, but I'd prefer to create a call back that runs before other code (sometimes known as a 'pre-hook', or 'before hook'.

Comment: Those callbacks get called with the original expression (https://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf), so I guess one could write a callback that re-runs the original expression. Obvious downside is that you would literally be executing everything twice..

Comment: @Axeman something similar came to my mind too, that was to try to intercept the original line and temporarily store it as a string then `eval()` it *after* the pre hook code. I had a quick look at the source for `addTaskCallback()` thinking I could possibly manipulate it to do just that, but it went more or less straight to c code, which i'm inept at `.Call(.C_R_addTaskCallback, f, data, !missing(data)`

Comment: Why do you have store it as a string or go to the C code? The function you provide to `addTaskCallback()` receives four arguments, the first of which is the original expression. You can `eval()` that expression at the R level, by including that in you callback function, right?

Comment: Although, I'm not sure how to access that result, and it is a really ugly solution in the first place, so I wouldn't recommend it..

Comment: @Axeman yeah, I like the idea of trying to hack `addTaskCallback()` to get a pre hook to work, but ultimately I'd try to do it 'properly' (e.g. in a similar style of the `addTaskCallback()` but especially for post hooks.

Comment: @Axeman if there's not currently a way to achieve pre hooks, it might be something that can be asked for: https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues

Although I wouldn't expect it would be a top priority, given it's not a high demand feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if you write your own front end.  It doesn't need to be a full front end like RStudio, simply something to collect inputs and evaluate them.

For example, if you want to do this on source code from a file, this is the sort of thing you could do:

```r
sourceWithHooks <- function(filename, prehook = NULL, posthook = NULL, envir = parent.frame(), ...) {
  exprs <- parse(filename)
  for (i in seq_along(exprs)) {
    expr <- exprs[[i]]
    if (is.function(prehook))
      prehook(expr, envir)
    res <- withVisible(eval(expr, envir = envir, ...))
    if (is.function(posthook))
      posthook(expr, res, envir)
  }
} 

prehook <- function(expr, envir) {
  cat(deparse(expr), "\n")
}

posthook <- function(expr, res, envir) {
  if (res$visible)
    print(res$value)
}

sourceWithHooks(somefile, prehook = prehook, posthook = posthook)
```

This doesn't do anything very fancy but it's the basic outline.